# Using ajax or jsonp to retrieve php source code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jsonp

Is there a way, using ajax or jsonp, to retrieve a php file source code?, the request is made by the same domain as the php files, I don't want the server to process the files, I only interesting with retrieval the content of the files, maybe there is a specific header used to request the server not to process the requested file?

The only solution I found is to change the file suffix, from `.php` to `.txt/.html/etc` but this solution is my last resort, if there is any other way I will be very thankful.

Comment: Have you tried changing the MIME type? PHP's is `application/x-httpd-php`. Have you also tried `dataType: 'html',` in your `$.ajax({});` parameters?

Comment: @D4V1D ajaxing is nothing else but HTTPing a .php file on server. That file *will* be executed *on* the server. If it's a .php file and you have no specific rule how to handle .php files in .htaccess or ini, it'll response as it should. returning *data*, not PHP *source* code.

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan for this this clarification. I was actually wondering about the type of request an Ajax call is. That is regular GET or POST `HTTP` so the file is still parsed.

Comment: Guys thank you I think I got my answer.

Comment: @D4V1D exactly. Unless the *server* is in *known* that it should handle a specific .php file as it were a text file. in that case you'd get a normal preview of the complete `<?php` stuff in it among the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a php wrapper which your ajax code could request and pass in the file you would like to see the contents of:

Request via ajax: http://yourdomain.com/get_content.php?file=test.php

get_content.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['file'] && file_exists($_GET['file'])) {
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
}
?>
```

Please do not use the code above in production mode, it is just an idea how to handle your problem.

Comment: Yes, in production what if someone would access to `http://yourdomain.com/get_content.php?file=../../../../../../../etc/passwd`? :)